# Vaadin динамическое изменение иконки и текста у кнопки?

Tags: java, button, text, icon, vaadin

Всем привет, помогите решить задачу)

Собственно задача состоит, в том что бы по нажатию на кнопку у нее менялась иконка и текст
Вот код(Иконка и текст не меняются):

```
Button btnSearch = new Button("Apply filter");
btnSearch.setIcon(FontAwesome.SEARCH);
btnSearch.addClickListener(e->{
   e.getButton().setIcon(FontAwersome.CANCEL)
   e.getButton().setCaption("Cancel filter");
});
```

Comment: http://pasted.co/9fd1b668  нормально работает. сверяете

Comment: а кнопка добавлена в layout ?

Answer (score 0):

попробуй в конце дописать

```
e.getButton().updateUI();
```

или

```
e.getButton().repaint();
```

это должно заставлять swing рисовывать кнопку заново